# Oracle DB backup script not running

Tags: database, oracle, cron

I am trying to make a backup using crontab on a linux machine.

I have a short script :

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=<oracle_home_directory>
DATE=`date +%F_%H-%M-%S`

echo $DATE

/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/expdp system/oramanager full=Y parallel=4 directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=prod1-ecmdb1-$DATE.dmp logfile=prod-ecmdb1-$DATE.log compression=all
```

I have placed this script in crontab as such:

```
02 17 * * * cd /u01/app/oracle/admin/ecmdb1/dpdump/ && /u01/app/oracle/admin/ecmdb1/dpdump/backup.sh > /tmp/test.out
```

But the script does not run. It says in logs that :

```
UDE-12162: operation generated ORACLE error 12162
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

If I run the whole script line manually, it works fine. But doesnt work fine using cron. Do I need to setup variables ?

Answer (score 1):

Set ORACLE_HOME AND ORACLE_SID

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/oracle/product/......
export ORACLE_SID=dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `export ORACLE_SID=<...>`
And make sure the cron is set up under the same user, not root.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working script, after using all the help from Community.

Create a Bash file(used [nano](https://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/sedwards/Nano/UsefulNanoKeyCommands.html#CopyAndPaste) here):

```
nano DBBackUp.sh
```

Copy the below code and edit the contents in angle brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=<OracleHomeDirectory>
export ORACLE_SID=<SID>
DATE=`date +%d%m%Y`
DATETIME=`date +%F_%H%M%S`
echo $DATETIME | tee DBBackUp_$DATE.log
echo "Exporting..." | tee -a DBBackUp_$DATE.log
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/expdp <SCHEMA/PASSWORD> directory=DP dumpfile=BACKUP$DATE.dmp | echo export.log | cat export.log >>  DBBackUp_$DATE.log
echo "Compressing..." | tee -a DBBackUp_$DATE.log
zip  BACKUP$DATE.zip BACKUP$DATE.dmp >> DBBackUp_$DATE.log
echo "Deleting..." | tee -a DBBackUp_$DATE.log
rm BACKUP$DATE.dmp 2>&1 | tee -a DBBackUp_$DATE.log | cat DBBackUp_$DATE.log
```

Create a cronjob:

```
00 13 28 04 * /home/oracle/DBBackUp/DBBackUp.sh
```

Above [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) executed at 01:00pm on 28th April 2020

System creates export.log in DP directory.

Here, all the files are in same location. [DP Directory]

Make sure that oracle user's having necessary permissions & ownership to the shell script.